# arduino + serialport communication + ruby

Tags: ruby, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm trying to turn on an LED connected to an Arduino from a ruby file, as well as sending a string from that Arduino to my ruby file / terminal. (I'm doing these two things separately, to avoid potential problems).

I'm using a USB port to connect Arduino - Computer, and the [serialport gem](https://github.com/hparra/ruby-serialport). I'm working in Linux.

**To receive the string on my computer:**

I have followed several tutorials that all recommend to run this ruby file:

```
require 'serialport'

port_str = '/dev/ttyACM0'
baud_rate = 9600
data_bits = 8
stop_bits = 1
parity = SerialPort::NONE

sp = SerialPort.new(port_str, baud_rate, data_bits, stop_bits, parity)

while(true) do
 message = sp.gets.chomp 
 puts message
end
```

And uploaded this to the Arduino:

```
uint8_t c;
int i;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);      // set baud rate
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);     // set pin 13 to be output for LED
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // start with LED off
}

void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {  // check if serial port has data

    // writes to computer
    Serial.println("Hello world");
  }
}
```

I got this error message: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError). When getting rid of .chomp, at some point I could get some parts of "Hello world" being printed on my terminal, such as "Hell", and then far later "o w", etc.

Now I don't even get anything anymore.

**To turn the led on:**

In the ruby file, I replaced the message part by

```
 sp.write('a')
```

And in the arduino file,

```
void loop() {

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {  // check if serial port has data
    c = Serial.read();              // read the byte

   if (c == 'a'){
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);  // turn on LED
        delay(500);              // wait 500 milliseconds
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);   // turn off LED
        delay(500);              // wait 500 milliseconds
     }
  }
}
```

The led turns on if I remove the condition (c == 'a'), but obviously I need it if I want the arduino to perform different actions.

I'm new to Serial communication, so I'm not quite sure where the error comes from, since I feel somehow *some* data seems to be transmitted.

Comment: First thing I notice: 2 different baud rates.

Comment: Damn!!!!!!!!!! It's probably that! Don't understand how I could have missed it. Will check, tx :'''

Comment: So sadly that wasn't the problem. I think it was an error when I copied my code over here, and having checked with my local sketch I still have the same problem with the same baud rates.